# How to change color of Switch toggle button using state?

Tags: android, css, react-native

If I have a Switch component as follows;

```
           <Switch
                trackColor={{ false: '#e57373', true: '#81c784' }}
                thumbColor='gray'
                ios_backgroundColor="gray"
                onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ toggle: value })}
                value={this.state.toggle}
            />
```

Can I change the color using a state value I have set e.g

```
 componentDidMount() {
    backgroundColor = this.props.dataBackgroundColor;
    primaryColor = this.props.dataPrimaryColor;

    this.setState({ background_color: backgroundColor })
    this.setState({ primary_color: primaryColor })

     console.log(this.state.primary_color) //#52A2C6
}
```

And then do something like;

```
 <Switch
                trackColor={{ false: '#e57373', true: this.state.primary_color }}
                thumbColor='gray'
                ios_backgroundColor="gray"
                onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ toggle: value })}
                value={this.state.toggle}
            />
```

At the moment, no error is thrown but the color is not updated.

Comment: try this  <Switch {...this.props}
                trackColor={{ false: '#e57373', true: this.state.primary_color }}
                thumbColor='gray'
                ios_backgroundColor="gray"
                onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ toggle: value })}
                value={this.state.toggle}
            />

Comment: @vijeeshin Thanks for that.  Tried to no avail.  Again, no error and the color just defaults to white. Should be the same color as printed in the console as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

Issue was with the props and how I am sharing the data between screens/components.

**SettingScreen.js**

```
const SettingsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
const { background_color, primary_color } = route.params;
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <Settings navigation={navigation} dataBackgroundColor={background_color} dataPrimaryColor={primary_color} />
    </View>
);
```

};

**settings.js**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
    backgroundColor = this.props.dataBackgroundColor;
    primaryColor = this.props.dataPrimaryColor;
    this.setState({ background_color: backgroundColor })
    this.setState({ primary_color: primaryColor })

    console.log(this.state.primary_color)
}
```